# pthread does not end competely

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

This is my code which I wrote it in c language and pthread:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5
#define TRUE 1
int numberOfLines ;
int sumCounter, subCounter, mulCounter, divCounter ;
int sumFileEnd, subFileEnd, mulFileEnd, divFileEnd ;
pthread_t *tid ;

clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

sem_t sumfull, sumEmpty ;
sem_t subfull, subEmpty ;
sem_t divfull, divEmpty ;
sem_t mulfull, mulEmpty ;

char sumBuff [5][25] ;
char subBuff [5][25] ;
char divBuff [5][25] ;
char mulBuff [5][25] ;

pthread_mutex_t sumMutex ;
pthread_mutex_t subMutex ;
pthread_mutex_t divMutex ;
pthread_mutex_t mulMutex ;

void initData(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&sumMutex, NULL)  ;
    pthread_mutex_init(&subMutex, NULL)  ;
    pthread_mutex_init(&divMutex, NULL)  ;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mulMutex, NULL)  ;

    sem_init(&sumfull, 0, 0) ;
    sem_init(&sumEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;
    sem_init(&subfull, 0, 0) ;
    sem_init(&subEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;
    sem_init(&divfull, 0, 0) ;
    sem_init(&divEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;
    sem_init(&mulfull, 0, 0) ;
    sem_init(&mulEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;

    sumCounter = subCounter = mulCounter = divCounter = 0 ;
    sumFileEnd = subFileEnd = mulFileEnd = divFileEnd = 0 ;
}

void *plusReadThread(){
    printf("Enter to the PRT\n");
    FILE *sumfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    sumFileEnd = 0;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *isSum ;
    int lineNumber = 1 ;
    if (lineNumber == 1){
        read = getline(&line, &len, sumfp) ;
        lineNumber ++ ;
    }
    while (!feof(sumfp)){
        printf("Enter to the PRTW\n");
        read = getline(&line, &len, sumfp) ;
        isSum = strchr(line, '+') ;
        if (isSum != NULL){
            sem_wait(&sumEmpty);
            printf("wait on sumEmpty\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&sumMutex) ;
            printf("Lock sumMutex\n");
            if(sumCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                char temp[20] ;
                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                strcat(temp, ".");
                strcat (temp, line);
                strcpy(sumBuff[sumCounter], temp);
                sumCounter ++;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&sumMutex);
            printf("Unlock sumMutex\n");
            sem_post(&sumfull);
            printf("Post on sumfull\n");
        }
        lineNumber ++;
    }
    if (feof(sumfp))
    {
        printf("SumFileEnd\n");
        sumFileEnd = 1;
    }
    fclose(sumfp);
}
void *plusExec(){
    printf("Enter to th PE\n");
    char *search = "+" ;
    char *temp1;
    char *temp2;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2 ;
    int operand1 ;
    int operand2 ;
    int result ;
    while (!sumFileEnd || sumCounter!=0){
        printf("Enter to the PEW\n");
        sem_wait(&sumfull);
        printf("Wait on sumfull\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&sumMutex);
        printf("Lock sumMutex\n");
        temp1 = strtok_r(sumBuff[sumCounter-1], search, &saveptr1) ;
        operand2 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, search, &saveptr1));
        temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
        operand1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
        result = operand1 + operand2 ;
        printf("Exex Sum result\n");
        printf("%d %d\n", atoi(temp2), result);
        sumCounter --;
        sem_post(&sumEmpty);
        printf("Post on sumEmpty\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&sumMutex);
        printf("Unlock sumMutex\n");
    }
    if(sumFileEnd && sumCounter==0)
        printf("Returned for end of work sum\n");

}

void *subReadThread(){
    printf("Enter to the SRT\n");
    FILE *subfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *isSub ;
    int lineNumber = 1 ;
    if (lineNumber == 1){
        read = getline(&line, &len, subfp) ;
        lineNumber ++ ;
    }
    while (!feof(subfp)){
        printf("Enter to the SRTW\n");
        read = getline(&line, &len, subfp) ;
        isSub = strchr(line, '-') ;
        if (isSub != NULL){
            sem_wait(&subEmpty);
            printf("Wait  subEmpty\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&subMutex) ;
            printf("Lock subMutex\n");
            if(subCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                char temp[20] ;
                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                strcat(temp, ".");
                strcat (temp, line);
                strcpy(subBuff[subCounter], temp);
                subCounter ++;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&subMutex);
            printf("Unlock subMutex\n");
            sem_post(&subfull);
            printf("Post on subfull\n");
        }
        lineNumber ++;
    }
    if (feof(subfp))
    {
        printf("SubFileEnd\n");
        subFileEnd = 1;
    }
    fclose(subfp);
}
void *subExec(){
    printf("Enter to the SE\n");
    char *search = "-" ;
    char *temp1;
    char *temp2;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2 ;
    int operand1 ;
    int operand2 ;
    int result ;
    while (!subFileEnd || subCounter!=0){
        printf("Enter to SEW \n");
        sem_wait(&subfull);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&subMutex);
        temp1 = strtok_r(subBuff[subCounter-1], search, &saveptr1) ;
        operand2 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, search, &saveptr1));
        temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
        operand1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
        result = operand1 - operand2 ;
        printf("Exec sub result\n");
        printf("%d %d\n", atoi(temp2), result);
        subCounter --;
        sem_post(&subEmpty);
        printf("Post on subEmpty\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&subMutex);
        printf("Unlock subMutex\n");
    }
    if(subFileEnd && subCounter==0)
        printf("Returned for end of work sub\n");
}

void *mulReadThread(){
    printf("Enter to the MRT\n");
    FILE *mulfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *isMul ;
    int lineNumber = 1 ;
    if (lineNumber == 1){
        read = getline(&line, &len, mulfp) ;
        lineNumber ++ ;
    }
    while (!feof(mulfp)){
        printf("Enter to the MRTW\n");
        read = getline(&line, &len, mulfp) ;
        isMul = strchr(line, '*') ;
        if (isMul != NULL){
            sem_wait(&mulEmpty);
            printf("Wait on mulEmpty\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mulMutex) ;
            printf("Lock mulMutex\n");
            if(mulCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                char temp[20] ;
                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                strcat(temp, ".");
                strcat (temp, line);
                strcpy(mulBuff[mulCounter], temp);
                mulCounter ++;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mulMutex);
            printf("Unlock mulMutex\n");
            sem_post(&mulfull);
            printf("Post on mulfull\n");
        }
        lineNumber ++;
    }
    if (feof(mulfp))
    {
        printf("MulFileEnd\n");
        mulFileEnd = 1;
    }
    fclose(mulfp);
}
void *mulExec(){
    printf("Enter to the ME\n");
    char *search = "*" ;
    char *temp1;
    char *temp2;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2 ;
    int operand1 ;
    int operand2 ;
    int result ;
    while (!mulFileEnd || mulCounter!=0){
        printf("Enter to the MEW\n");
        sem_wait(&mulfull);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mulMutex);
        temp1 = strtok_r(mulBuff[mulCounter-1], search, &saveptr1) ;
        operand2 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, search, &saveptr1));
        temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
        operand1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
        result = operand1 * operand2 ;
        printf("Exec mul result\n");
        printf("%d %d\n", atoi(temp2), result);
        mulCounter --;
        sem_post(&mulEmpty);
        printf("Post on mulEmpty\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mulMutex);
        printf("Unlock mulMutex\n");
    }
    if(mulFileEnd && mulCounter==0)
        printf("Returned for end of work mul\n");

}

void *divReadThread(){
    printf("Enter to the DRT\n");
    FILE *divfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *isDiv ;
    int lineNumber = 1 ;
    if (lineNumber == 1){
        read = getline(&line, &len, divfp) ;
        lineNumber ++ ;
    }
    while (!feof(divfp)){
        printf("Enter to the DRTW\n");
        read = getline(&line, &len, divfp) ;
        isDiv = strchr(line, '/') ;
        if (isDiv != NULL){
            sem_wait(&divEmpty);
            printf("Wait on divEmpty\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&divMutex) ;
            printf("Lock divMutex\n");
            if(divCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                char temp[20] ;
                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                strcat(temp, ".");
                strcat (temp, line);
                strcpy(divBuff[divCounter], temp);
                divCounter ++;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&divMutex);
            printf("Unlock divMutex\n");
            sem_post(&divfull);
            printf("Post on divfull\n");
        }
        lineNumber ++;
    }
    if (feof(divfp))
    {
        printf("DivFileEnd\n");
        divFileEnd = 1;
    }
    fclose(divfp);
}
void *divExec(){
    printf("Enter to the DE\n");
    char *search = "/" ;
    char *temp1;
    char *temp2;
    char *saveptr1, *saveptr2 ;
    float operand1 ;
    float operand2 ;
    float result ;
    while (!divFileEnd || divCounter!=0){
        printf("Enter to the DEW\n");
        sem_wait(&divfull);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&divMutex);
        temp1 = strtok_r(divBuff[divCounter-1], search, &saveptr1) ;
        operand2 = atof(strtok_r(NULL, search, &saveptr1));
        temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
        operand1 = atof(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
        result = operand1 / operand2 ;
        printf("Exec div result\n");
        printf("%d %f\n", atoi(temp2), result);
        divCounter --;
        sem_post(&divEmpty);
        printf("Post on divEmpty\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&divMutex);
        printf("Unlock divMutex\n");
    }
    if(divFileEnd && divCounter==0)
        printf("Returned for end of work div\n");

}
int main (int argc, char* argv []){
    initData() ;
    tid = (pthread_t*)malloc(8*sizeof(pthread_t)) ;
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,plusReadThread,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,plusExec,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[2],NULL,subReadThread,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[3],NULL,subExec,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[4],NULL,divReadThread,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[5],NULL,divExec,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[6],NULL,mulReadThread,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[7],NULL,mulExec,NULL);

    pthread_join(tid[0] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[2] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[3] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[4] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[5] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[6] , NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[7] , NULL);

    printf("Hi\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

It creates 4 threads each for one operator to execute. When I do `add`, `div` and `mul` threads,for a sample file like:

```
24
3707 + 1056
3707 + 1056
3707 + 1056
3707 + 1056
3707 + 1056
3707 + 1056
4460 - 2396
4460 - 2396
4460 - 2396
4460 - 2396
4460 - 2396
4460 - 2396
2088 / 1958
2682 / 3028
1809 / 4601
4297 / 2841
2222 / 2551
4459 / 1466
1520 * 1189
4544 * 777
2987 * 2748
3028 * 3328
633 * 270
633 * 270
```

Which has more than 5 `mul` after each other, it does not end completely.
This is trace stack:

```
    Starting program: /home/emadhelmi/Desktop/OSPthread/Final/a 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 18953)]
Enter to the PRT
Enter to the PRTW
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ff5700 (LWP 18954)]
.
.
.

[Thread 0x7fffef7fe700 (LWP 18961) exited]
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7bc566b in pthread_join ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bc566b in pthread_join ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000401e73 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdff8) at cm.c:363
(gdb)
```

but it printed all the results.

Comment: Loop condition `while (!feof(divfp)){` [is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You can simply use `while( (read = getline(&line, &len, mulfp)) != -1)` as loop condition. Try to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's *lot* of code. Your problem is not clear from the description either.

Comment: @BlueMoon i corrected the loops but still the problem is remainig:the program after all executions wait and does not return to main and then does not `exit(0)` here is the output of the sample above with trace stack [OutPut](http://pastebin.com/xChk37gf)

Comment: That indicates one or more threads not completing. `sumFileEnd` is is read by both thread *read* and *exec* threads without any synchronization. There's a race condition. The same issue with other threads too.

Comment: The copy and paste is strong in this code. You could pass the differences between the functions as parameters and only have one `exec` and one `readThread`.

Comment: Apart from the fact that all of your `void* function()`s have the wrong signature for `pthread_create()`, none of them `return` anything. Also, all of them `sem_wait()` on one semaphore and `sem_post()` **on a different semaphore**.